# MySQL Connector C++ build from source in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

I am trying to build the mySQL Connector C++ from source in Visual Studio 2013 Running CMake produces a project file, but that project file doesn't compile because of a big list errors and an even bigger list of warnings.

```
Building Custom Rule C:/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3/test/framework/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3\test\framework\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
  test_suite.cpp
C:\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3\cppconn/exception.h(61): warning C4251: sql::SQLException::sql_state: class "std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>" needs to have dll-interface to be used class "sql::SQLException"
  test_factory.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(546): error C2146: syntax error : missing ")" before identifier "_Str"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(546): error C2065: _Str: undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(546): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(546): error C2365: _strtoi64: redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cstdlib(39): error C2039: strtoll: is not a member of '`global namespace''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cstdlib(39): error C2873: strtoll: symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

Could some one please list all the steps in successfully compiling the C++ Connector?

Comment: theses sources were not designed to be used within visual studio. Even if you manage to successfully compile it, the results will be not like you think they should be - you're using a completely different toolchain, MSVC has its own quirks and shines where other chains fail ... it will always lead to problems. Either convert the whole project completely or compile like its supposed to be compiled, everything else _WILL_ give you headaches, i've got some experience on the subject .... it isnt worth the effort.

Comment: @specializt Thank you very much for your reply!!! But i can't understand - why it work(compile) in VS2012

Comment: MSVC differs vastly from many other toolchains - its quite unpredictable. In this case, you appear to be linking against microsoft-libraries whereas OSS-libraries are expected ... my best guess is : you need toolchains and libraries like MinGW. But thats only a GUESS.